# c++ print the element of list of array

Tags: c++

I have the following code and I want to print each element in the array.

```
struct pckt
{
    float gen_time;
    int node_id;
    bool last; 
    int seq;
    float end_time;
}

list<pckt> nodelist[51];

pckt newpckt;
newpckt.gen_time = inp;
newpckt.node_id = i;
newpckt.last = false;
newpckt.seq = 1;
newpckt.end_time = 1.0;

nodelist[i].push_back(newpckt);

// I wnat to print each element in array list.
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a list. You have a array with 51 elements of a list to pcks.
So to print those you need to iterate over the array and print the list elements.
E.g:

```
for(int i=0; i < 51; ++i)
{
    std::for_each(nodelist[i].begin(), nodelist[i].end(), 
        [](const pckt& e){
            std::cout << e.node_id << std::endl;
        });
}
```